# Shifted Fourier transform

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Please can some one help and give me a  direction to evaluate the following shifted Fourier transform:
\begin{alignat}{2}
       s(x_c) =&\frac{1}{\Delta x_0} \int_{x_c-\Delta x_0}^{x_c+\Delta x_0}f_{b}(x-x_c)exp(jx)dx
\end{alignat}
When $f_{b}(x-x_c)=1$ then I am able to derive the previous integration which is :
\begin{alignat}{2}
       s(x_c) =&\frac{1}{\Delta x_0} \int_{x_c-\Delta x_0}^{x_c+\Delta x_0}exp(jx)dx\\
              =& sinc(\frac{\Delta x_0}{2})exp(jx_c)
\end{alignat}
For a generale case where the Fourier transform of $f_{b}$ equal to $F_{b}$ what we obtained? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the integral by changing variables. Let say $u=x-x_c$, then $du=dx$ and the lower and upper bounds of integral will be $-\Delta x_0$ and $+\Delta x_0$, so:
$$s(x_0) = \frac{1}{\Delta x_0} \int _{-\Delta x_0} ^{+\Delta x_0} f_b (u) e^{j(u+x_c)} du$$

$$ = \frac{e^{jx_c}}{\Delta x_0} \int _{-\Delta x_0} ^{+\Delta x_0} f_b (u) e^{ju} du$$

So if you define $\int _{-\Delta x_0} ^{+\Delta x_0} f_b (u) e^{ju} du$ as the Fourier transform of $f_b(x)$ then:
$$ s(x_0)=\frac{e^{jx_c}}{\Delta x_0} F_b(\Delta x_0).$$

NOTE: Actually it is not correct to call $s(x_0)$ shifted Fourier transform. As in Fourier transform the limits should be from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and also the output is not a function of frequency variable.

Comment: Thank you so much Sina for the derivation and your advice.